# Check if interval exists, if so, clear the interval and start a new one

Tags: javascript, intervals

I'm working on a countdown date script. However, the environment I'm working in does not refresh the page on submission, so I'm having an issue with multiple intervals being created. I believe if there was a way to check if there is an interval running, then to clear it and create a new one. But I'm not sure of how to do this. Of course, if there is a better strategy than how I currently have my code set up, then feel free to provide that as well.

My Code:

```
//get ready for a-togglin'
var finishedMessage = document.getElementById('finshedMessage');
//get dates value
var dateValue = document.getElementById('dateInput').innerText;

var dateEntered = new Date(dateValue);

//set the date we're counting down too
var targetDate = new Date(dateEntered).getTime();

//Update the countdown every second
var countInterval = setInterval(function() {
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  //get time remaining from now
  var timeRemaining = targetDate - now;

  //time calculations : days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(timeRemaining / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((timeRemaining % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((timeRemaining % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((timeRemaining % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  //When the countdown is finished, report back completion text
  if (timeRemaining <= 0 || NaN) {
    finishedMessage.style.display = "inline-block";
    clearInterval(countInterval);
  } else {
    //if day is over a year count the years remaining if no years just count       days
    if (days > 365) {
      var years = Math.floor(days / 365);
      days = days % 365;
      document.getElementById("report").innerHTML = years + "Y " + days + "D " + hours + "H " + minutes + "M " + seconds + "s ";
    } else {
      //report the remaining time to report div
      document.getElementById("report").innerHTML = days + "D " + hours + "H " + minutes + "M " + seconds + "s ";
    }
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: if (countInterval) clearInterval(countInterval)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid there's not how to clear all intervals declared without having the value returned from them. But you can save the reference to the global `window` object when running it for the first time, so you can reset it whenever you want:

```
if (window.countInterval) clearInterval(window.countInterval)
window.countInterval = setInterval(function () {
  /* your code here */
})
```

Comment: Perfect thank you so much sir, this worked. Have a great day!

Answer (score 2):

It is not an error to call `clearInterval` for interval id already stopped. So you can do just

```
clearInterval(intervalId);
intervalId = setInterval(.....);
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I keep track of the interval ID's is to push them into an array.

```
//This is to keep track of intervals and timeouts
if( typeof ID == "undefined" )
{ var ID = []; }
// make sure no intervals are running
ClearAll();
// start your interval like this
ID.push(
    setInterval( function(){  }, 200  )
);
// function to clear all running intervals in the array
function ClearAll(){
    for(let i = 0; i < ID.length; i++){
        clearInterval(  ID[ i ]  );
    }
}
```